QGIS 3.xx Mac Version installation clarification - What gets installed from single dmg file?
Can someone clarify what is installed exactly when I download the Mac versions of QQIS from the QGIS.org homepage?  The .dmg file gets downloaded and I can drag the application to the Applications folder.  What I am wondering is are all the extra components also bundled and included in this single application? GDAL, Python, etc.
Or will these have to be installed separately?  If so, where and what do I need to install to make sure it all works.
I will be teaching a class this fall and want to direct students using Macs to the correct resources to download and install QGIS.
Hopefully the current LTR version includes GDAL, Python, etc.
I installed QGIS through MacPorts on my M1 laptop and already have the components necessary to run the application so I am not sure what the standalone installer will install if one just drags and drops application into Applications folder.
Also, if someone could provide an estimated disk space requirement for QGIS and associated files (GDAL, Python, etc) this would be helpful.  I am guessing about 3-5 GB of hard drive space (not including any data to be used).
I want to know what is needed for a person who has not ever installed QGIS on a Mac so they can get up and running.  I know about the security workaround.
I can't find anything that answers this specifically.

Thank you for this.  I will remove the Windows part.   Much appreciated.

I just mounted the QGS 3.34 LTR DMG and poked around in it using a file explorer (not using a Mac) and found it includes

GDAL 3.3.2,
Python 3.9 and
GRASS 7.8

So should have everything you need for a standard install.
Uncompressed it's 3.5GB.
